# How to modify the Discount caption in shopping cart

Tags: checkout, cart, discount

If I apply 2 discount codes, I end up with a caption in my sub-total area will be :

```
Discount (discount number one, discount number two)
```

with the discount labels in brackets and separated by a comma

I want them as below

```
Discount 
   - discount number one
   - discount number two
```

With the discount labels shown as a list

I can't locate which file is doing this generation of the Discount label.

It is for use in Magento EE

Answer (score 3):

To create beautiful discount [breakdown](http://amasty.com/special-promotions.html) we:
1. changed the template app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/default.phtml for the block `Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default` via rewrite;
2. added observer to the items validation and collected prices/names in the address object;
3. added collected info  to the `$address->addTotal()` call inside `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount` class;

```
$address->addTotal(array(
            'code'      => $this->getCode(),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount'),
            'value'     => $amount,
            'full_info' => $address->getDiscountDescription(), // <-- new data
        ));
```

The result looks as:

[image: discount]

Comment: Can you please explain more? I did not understand which observer I have to use and where I add my above code?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug issues like this is to [Enable Template Path hint in Magento](http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/enable-template-path-hint-in-magento/)

Template

- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/default.phtml

Block

- Mage_Checkout_Block_Total_Default

Comment: thanks, already got that, but that did not help me enough.

Answer (score 0):

The part where the description is set is in the `fetch`-method in `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote/Discount.php`.

The important lines are:

```
$description = $address->getDiscountDescription();
...
$title = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Discount (%s)', $description);
```

`getDiscountDescription()` refers to the `discount_description` column in the   `sales_flat_quote_address` table.

According to `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` the discount description can be set as string or array:

```
 * @method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address setDiscountDescription(string $value)
 * @method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address setDiscountDescriptionArray(array $value)
```

So my guess would be to rewrite `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount` and adapt your `$description`there.

Comment: no, I have one discount for a product and another discount for another product. made through shopping cart rules.

Comment: and for the database thing, I do not check as they are surely not stored together, they are 2 separated rules, therefore, the caption is generated when creating the shopping cart page.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer